# Remove leading lines from a text file using c

Tags: c

I have an assignment coding in C attempting to remove the leading white spaces from a file using C instead of using shell.
I currently have a program that removes all spaces from a program. I just can not figure how who to make it only remove spaces at the beginning of the line before the actual text. Very new to coding in c so im sorry if this seems like a simple question to ask. Also i have my file hardcoded in but i would like to be able to pass in any text file.
For clarification I am only trying to remove leading spaces and trying to do so from a test file that is passed through the command line. I am not using a string.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
   FILE *fp;
   char p;


   fp = fopen("mountainList.txt", "r");

   while((p=getc(input))!=EOF) {
     if(p != 32) 

   printf("%c",p);

   }
     fclose(input);

}
```

```
Example text file:

           this is a test file
    this is a file of text
              text is in this file
```

```
Example output:

this is a test file
this is a file of text
text is in this file
```

Comment: You'll need a bit more code inside the while loop. A variable to track whether or not you are at the start of a line, and a check for newline characters to set it. Also, learn to indent properly and get into the habit of using braces on every if().

Comment: Do you want to modify the file itself, or only echo the output and leave the file untouched?

Comment: I want to leave the file alone but remove all leading spaces of the file in the output

Comment: that question is asking how to remove white space from a string. i am trying to remove only leading space from a text file that is passed through the command line.

Comment: ...and don't forget that getc() returns an int, not a char.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Just need a bit more code in the loop. Here's how I might do it (your style of coding might be different--like the Yoda conditions):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
   FILE *fp;
   int p;
   int at_start = 1;

   fp = fopen("mountainList.txt", "r");

   while (EOF != (p = getc(input))) {
     if (at_start && ' ' == p) continue;
     putc(p);
     at_start = ('\n' == p);
   }
   fclose(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *trimLeading(char line[])
{
    char *p;

    for (p = line; *p && isspace(*p); ++p) ;

    return p;
}

void printTrimmedLns(FILE *fp)
{
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp))
        printf("%s", trimLeading(line));
}
```

Call as such:

```
printTrimmedLns(stdin); /* or whatever input stream you need */
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes on coding. Don't use hardcoded filenames or numbers (called *"magic-numbers"*), e.g.

```
fp = fopen("mountainList.txt", "r");
...
if(p != 32)
```

They make your code difficult to read and more importantly, difficult to maintain as the length of your programs grow. Instead, pass your filename to your program as an argument or read the filename from within your code. Instead of using the *magic-number* `32`, use the character literal `' '` so it is clear that a space is intended.

If you need a numeric constant, or a string constant, `#define` them at the beginning of your code. That provides a single convenient location to make a single change if changes are later needed.

While there is nothing wrong with using `getc` (`fgetc`), consider using a *line-oriented* input function to read a line of input at a time, such as `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`. You can then make use of string functions that can automatically report the number of whitespace characters that must be removed.

An alternative to checking every character and keeping an index or advancing a pointer, you can make a single call to `strspn` providing the buffer containing your line and then a string defining the whitespace characters to consider, and it will return the initial number of characters in your line made up entirely of whitespace.

For example, the following takes the filename to read as the first argument to the program (or reads from `stdin` by default if no filename is given) and then after *validating* the file is open for reading, reads a line-at-a-time, passing the line to `strspn` along with the string containing the whitespace characters `" \t"` (space, tab). The return of `strspn` is the initial number of characters made up entirely of the characters in your whitespace string -- which you can then use as the offset (or index) to print your line omitting the leading whitespace, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define WS " \t"        /* leading whitespace characters to remove */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[MAXC];    /* buffer to hold line (don't skimp on buffer size) */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp))                  /* read each line */
        printf ("%s", &line[strspn (line, WS)]);    /* output w/o leading ws */

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

Or if you prefer printing using a pointer and offset, you could replace the call to `printf` with:

```
        printf ("%s", line + strspn (line, WS));    /* output w/o leading ws */
```

(**note:** if you want to remove lines containing all whitespace, check for a line-ending at the offset returned by `strspn` and simply skip printing the line)

Using your example input would result in the following:

```
$ /bin/removews <dat/wslines.txt
this is a test file
this is a file of text
text is in this file
```

As mentioned in the beginning, there is nothing wrong with taking a *character-oriented* approach to reading the file with `getc`, but know the other option of a *line-oriented* approach reading the entire line into a buffer can then make the functions in `string.h` available for use on the buffer itself.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.